# Java: How to add scroll bars to a GUI window implemented via java.awt.frame?

Tags: java, swing, awt, scrollbars, imagej

I have been working on ImageJ and **need to add scroll bars in a plugin: [Weka_segmentation](http://fiji.sc/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=fiji.git;a=blob;f=src-plugins/Trainable_Segmentation/trainableSegmentation/Weka_Segmentation.java;h=9196d643cea8ff275107ec26909514958e768453;hb=HEAD)**
It implements java.awt.Frame to ij.gui.ImageWindow,  which is implemented by a stackwindow class, which is in turn implemented by a customwindow class. I have to add scroll bars in this class. Is there any east, short way?

Comment: That code **imports** `java.awt.Frame` but actually **uses** a `javax.swing.JFrame` with Swing components.

Answer (score 3):

Try this....

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(Component);
```

**Component here will signify the one which needs scrolling...**

Comment: I think we should sort out whether Swing, AWT or a mixture is needed for this before jumping in with answers (that would create a mix of AWT & Swing).

Comment: Ya thats absoultely right..... but i gave him a quick fix reply, that usually Works... , and it does ! But your point is absolutely right.

Comment: thanks, but i can't get how to implement a scroll pane in the plugin, maybe you could take a look at the code, there's a customwindow class there that's used as the mane GUI pane

Comment: Email the entire code on my email..       vivek.mitra786@gmail.com , i am at work now as soon as i get sometime i will implement it

Answer (score 1):

I'm the main developer of that plugin. Where do you want the scroll bars?

You may get a detailed answer if you write to the main Fiji developer list: https://groups.google.com/group/fiji-devel

ignacio